# How to send json Azure DevOps request from c#?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

As per MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) in order to send a json request to Azure DevOps we should use the following code:

{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.WorkItemType",
    "value": "Task"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.State",
    "value": "To Do"
  }

My question is how to use this piece of code from C#?

Comment: Did you look at the "Getting started" link in the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I did look at it but did not see where it uses similar code to what I have posted. It is using a url to send the request.

Comment: Read more closely. There is a section that provides a link to sample code and client libraries you can use from C#.

Comment: The sample link does not use json code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, we use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json.JsonPatchDocument` to pack a completed request body Json, then pass it into the method.

See below sample:

```
var patchDocument = new 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json.JsonPatchDocument();
patchDocument.Add(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json.JsonPatchOperation() {
                Operation=Operation.Add,
                Path= "/fields/System.WorkItemType",
                Value="Task"
            });
patchDocument.Add(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json.JsonPatchOperation()
            {
                Operation = Operation.Add,
                Path = "/fields/System.State",
                Value = "To Do"
            });
```